# Hash primary key postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I already have a table but it doesn't have a primary key ID column. I would like to create the column with hash. So right now what I've done is create the column (id) as a self-incrementing primary key column and tried using this query to hash it:

```
CREATE index ON table USING hash (id)
```

However after I run the query nothing seems to change for the column it's still displaying 1, 2, 3...

Comment: That's a hash-type index. Why would an index alter the contents of the column?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Why do you think an index would _change_ data in the table?

Comment: So I would like to have a more sophisticated primary id. Right now the id column is 1,2,3... and I would like to have something like 32219nf3 in each row. I thought if I applied hash that would alter the data.

Comment: What's wrong with 1,2,3,4? Why do you think anything else would be "more sophisticated"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879975/1706846) *The Impaler* has given.

I believe what you are trying to achieve is to alter the type of your already existing `id` column. Additionally you have to change the default value of id to get a hashed id for every new row.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  label TEXT
);

INSERT INTO test (label) VALUES ('v1'), ('v2'), ('v3'), ('v4');

ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id TYPE text USING md5(id::TEXT);
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT md5(nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('test', 'id'))::TEXT);

INSERT INTO test (label) VALUES ('v5');
```

In this case `md5` was used, you could also use the `digest` function of the `pgcrypto` module for other hashing methods.

**But**, one disadvantage is an increased disk space usage.

I'm not sure if there are any performance benefits.

Answer (score 2):

No.

I think what you are doing is not a good practice. The primary key is not meant to be visible. It's an internal row identifier. Who cares what value it has? As long as it is unique, that's enough.

Well... unless you want to use "natural keys" but I have a strong opinion against those. It's good they are taught in school so you know what you should not use.

Now, if you want the PK to have some specific format, then it's because you want it to be visible to other processes or even people. Then, it will be subject to requirements changes ("I want the PK in upper case only!", or "Please prepend it with the state code!"). If you follow this path you are asking for trouble.

Solution? Create a secondary column that is also **unique**. That one is not a PK and you can even generate it based on other parameters. In time you can even change it, without all the side effects a PK has, like foreign key references, locking, etc.

Heck, you can have twenty secondary unique identifiers, for any esoteric use you may think of. Just don't mess with the primary key. Keep it simple.